# sending jsonreader parameters with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

How Can I send the jqgrid (jsonreader) parameters with ajax???

```
$.ajax({

    url:'admin/report_table.php',
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
       if(!data) data=0;
      // alert(data);
        my_data = data;
    }
});

jQuery("#report_data").jqGrid({
        data: my_data,
        datatype: 'local',
        mtype: 'Get',
        height: "auto",
        width: 'auto',
        rowNum: 20,
        rownumbers: true,
        rowList: [10,20,30],
        colNames:['name','date'],
                      colModel :[
                        {name:'name', index:'name', width:100},
                        {name:'date', index:'date', width:150,align:"center"}],
        pager: "#p_report_data",
        viewrecords: true,
              toolbar: [true, 'both'],
        caption: "Report",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
data: { param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2' }
```

for the [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call.
[jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) uses postData.

```
postData: { param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the (`data:{}`) with ajax but the `jsonreader` parameters is not sending ..
when I use (`postdata:{}`) with jqgrid it's working OK, but I am having a problem when using the jQuery grid with dialog (load the grid in dialog) the dialog keep the old parameters, when I send another request it's not changing, that's why I want to use ajax, cause it's working, but I can't see the `jasonreader` parameters.